# What is the most simple approach to add an ordinary page to angular 2+ SPA?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular 5 SPA with routing done via @uirouter/angular. All routes inside my app are protected with login page like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(loggedIn$ | async)">
 <!-- LOGIN FORM "PAGE" HERE -->
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async">
 <!-- OTHER "PAGES" HANDLING BY ROUTER HERE -->
 <ui-view></ui-view>
</ng-container>
```

Thus any app page like "/#/xxx" entering without logged in state results in showing login form and if login is succesfull showing the page itself.
But now I need to have a special page via the app with own address like "/special-page". So it should not be SPA page with "#" since not all domain providers handle internal "#" routes correctly (I had an experience when all internal routes were masked by domain provider, user could enter the app only from root route and all internal navigation didn't change that address in browser). The only approach I see now is to put completely separated new application on "/special-page" route. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use router [guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) ([medium article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)) to protect routes. Then, if you apply [lazy-loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) to the new route, the module, view and components will only be pulled when the route is activated.

So your app-routing module will have an entry like the following:

```
  {
    path: 'special-page',
    loadChildren: 'app/special-area/special.module#AppSpecialModule',
    canActivate: [IsSpecialGuard]
  },
```

The guard (something like this):

```
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (allowed()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/404');
    return false;
  }
```

There is a lot of documentation on lazy loading and guards, I won't write it all here, but hopefully it leads you to the right direction. Best of luck!